# set column width using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have html table with format

```
<div id="divOutputWindow">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>/* Set Width 10 Px */ </td>
<td>/* Set Width 20 Px */ </td>
</tr>
<tr>
/* Same for all tr */
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

i.e. first td has width 10 px next td 15 px next td 20 px...likewise

What i Tried is

```
$('#divOutputWindow').find('table').$('tbody > tr > td').css('width', '10px');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Loop trough each `<td>` inner your `#divOutputWindow`.
- Use `.each();` for that, in the loop you can acces the current
  DOM-object by `$(this)`.
- Define a minimum and a stepsize, use `$(this).index();` for counting.
- Then use the `.css('attr','value');` command to manipulate your
  current `<td>`. It's a setter of the css attribute. Don't forget to put `"px"` at the end.

The Code:

```
$('#divOutputWindow td').each(function() {
    var min = 10;                                  // Define a minimum
    var step = 5 * $(this).index();                // Define Step(your step is 5 here)
    $(this).css('width', (min + step) + "px");     // css attribute of your <td> width:15px; i.e.
});
```

Did it work?

***Edit: i saw that @billyonecan already posted something similar, test both examples, mine works (i tested it)***

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
$('div#divOutputWindow table tr td').eq(0).css('width','10px');
$('div#divOutputWindow table tr td').eq(1).css('width','20px');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use the CSS3 pseudo classes?

Like

```
td:first-child
{
    width: 10px;
}
```

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses

## Edit

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfDb9/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interested in this one which is working great: http://jsbin.com/ojunor/1/edit

```
$('#divOutputWindow table tr').each(function(){
    $('td:eq(0)',this).attr({"width":"10"}).text('10');
    $('td:eq(1)',this).attr({"width":"20"}).text('20');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('#divOutputWindow td').attr('width', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you meant. Basically, loop over your `<td>`'s, and set the width in relation to the element index, eg:

```
$('#divOutputWindow td').each(function() {
  var step = 5; $td = $(this);
  $td.width(10 + (step * $td.index()));
});
```

You basically end up with:

```
<tr>
  <td style="width: 10px;"> ... </td>
  <td style="width: 15px;"> ... </td>
  <td style="width: 20px;"> ... </td>
</tr>
```

.. and so on

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NjCH/)

Answer (score 0):

Though, ideally this is best done with css (pseudo-)classes, you can use this code:

```
// Cache the td selector
var $td = $('#divOutputWindow table tr td');

$td.eq(0).width(10);
$td.eq(1).width(20);
...
```

Here's a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/isuwes/1/edit)